# How can i save attributes values against product ids in magetno

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I add Products attributes value against product ids's. I want to add attributes values for specific product id using code.My code for products attribute is

```
$attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

//Load the particular attribute by id
//Here 73 is the id of 'manufacturer' attribute
$attr_model->load(73);

//Create an array to store the attribute data
$data = array();

//Create options array
$values = array(
    //15 is the option_id of the option in 'eav_attribute_option_value' table
    15 => array(
            0 => 'Apple'    //0 is current store id, Apple is the new label for the option
        ),
    16 => array(
            0 => 'HTC'
        ),
    17 => array(
            0 => 'Microsoft'
        ),
);

//Add the option values to the data
$data['option']['value'] = $values;

//Add data to our attribute model
$attr_model->addData($data);

//Save the updated model
try {
    $attr_model->save();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
    $session->addSuccess(
        Mage::helper('catalog')->__('The product attribute has been saved.'));

    /**
     * Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation
     */
    Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
    $session->setAttributeData(false);
    return;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $session->addError($e->getMessage());
    $session->setAttributeData($data);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after search i find some code that save my attribute values and than i store them against products.This is my code :

```
public static function getAttributeOptionId($arg_attribute, $arg_value,$id)
     {
        $id = $id;
        //load the attribute by attribute code
    $entityTypeID = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId();
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);
    $type =  $attribute->getBackendType();

 foreach($options as $option) {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value) {
           $arrk[] = $option['label'];
        }
    }

$optiont = self::getAttributeOptionValue($arg_attribute, $arg_value);

if(!$optiont){
    $value['option'] = array($arg_value,$arg_value);
    $result = array('value' => $value);
    $attribute->setData('option',$result);
    $attribute->save();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $product->setMyAttribute($arg_attribute)->save();


 }
    return 0;



    }
    public function getAttributeOptionValue($arg_attribute, $arg_value) {
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach($options as $option) {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value) {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}.
```

Where $arg_attribute is the attriubte code and $arg_value is his value.Id is product id for specific sku.I am saving records in my custom module.If anyone know issue with this code please inform me.Thanks